# How can I set memory limit and execution timeout for a specific IP address using php-fpm and nginx?

Tags: nginx, php

I need to set a different timeout and execution time for a third party server that needs to import the products and prices on my database.

Right now, they are telling me the php script is timing out. This is due to my configuration on php.ini. I'd like to be able to keep that configuration for everyone as I think that's the right configuration. But I also need them to be able to execute the script.

I guess there must be a way to do this either on nginx or php-fpm configurations. Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a NEW php-fpm config file for the specific 3rd party server and overwrite the php.ini setting, i.e.,

```
php_admin_value[max_execution_time] = 60
php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M
```

Then in nginx, set up a new location block with fastcgi pointing to the same port (or unix socket) your new php-fpm config file is listening to.